# Element-ui maximum effective value

Tags: vue.js, pagination, element-ui

I'm using el-pagination from Element-ui, but I'm having problems with the number of items per page, it only accepts 12 items per page, and I want to be able to show more, does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page-size` like:

```
<el-pagination
    :page-size="50">
</el-pagination>
```